# Datamerge - Excel to Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

I have a problem with a data merge. On several tutorials if they selected the CSV file, all the data loads up separately but when I select the CSV file, all data loads like this:

[image: Data merge window]

So I can't load them up separately. What I'm doing wrong?

### My steps:

1. make excel file with all my data
2. save this file
3. save the CSV file
4. open InDesign document
5. select data source
6. then I see this...

Comment: What does your csv file look like?

Comment: If the marked duplicate doesn't solve your issue please make an [edit] with further information and we can re-open your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very typical.

Indesign expects your CSV fields to be **comma** separated.
BUT... depending on your regional settings, Excel might export CSV with a **semicolon** as separator. Errr... we are not (yet) all americans. This seems to be your case... not american right? ^^

Sooo... two solutions:

1. Export Excel file as **.txt** file, **tab** separated. It works like a charm, this is what I would do.
2. You really want to use CSV. (If you're a Mac user... I don't know). If you're a Windows user: open Control Panel > Regional Settings, Advanced parameters: change **list separator** to comma.

Hope that helps

Comment: On a Mac you could always just open the csv in a code editor and do a find-replace on the semi-colons.

Comment: Sure. On a PC too.  But that's an unnecessary extra step. I meant I don't know how to change regional settings on a Mac. Anyhow, I still advise using tabbed .txt

Comment: that could be a dangerous step if your cell data contains a semi colon itself, +1 for tabs. This btw is the kind of format they use in the nordic countries, I heard, cells are split by semi colons while number decimal points are commas.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vinny! Yes, I'm not american, from Belgium here. The .txt file with tab separated works just fine! One more question Is CSV better to use than .txt? Or is this pretty much the same?

Comment: Good question. As far as I'm aware of, it's just a matter of separator. Commas or semicolons can be handled more easily in processes used for web development purposes, so in those cases, CSV is "better". Apart from that, I don't see much more differences. For InDesign data merge, none is better, both work as long as CSV is comma separated...